# JQuery - Output the class name of checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering whether or not it is possible to output the class name of checked checkboxes each time a checkbox is checked/unchecked? For example, I have 3 checkboxes. If I check one, it'll output its class name, if I then check a 2nd one it'll output the first checkbox class name + the 2nd class name. If I then uncheck the first checkbox, it'll only output the class name of the 2nd checkbox.. and so forth? I made a JSFiddle to get started... http://jsfiddle.net/LUtJF/

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    var classes = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").map(function() {
        return this.className;
    }).get().join(",");
    alert(classes);
});
```

[**Your fiddle, fiddled with.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/LUtJF/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eUse5/

Code:

```
function showChecked() {
    var s = '';
    $('input:checked').each(function() {
        if(s!='') s += ', ';
        s += $(this).attr('class');
    });
    alert(s);
}
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(showChecked);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cb = $('input[type=checkbox]');
    cb.change(function() {
        cb.each(function() {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                alert($(this).attr('class'));
            }  
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like

```
$(":checkbox").click(function(){
    var classes = "";
    $(':checked[class]').each(function(){ // this will filter only checked checkbox having class attribute
       classes += " "+$(this).attr("class");
    });
    alert(classes);
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LUtJF/7/